# Marquee with buttons inside a view SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, marquee

I'm trying to have a marquee horizontal scrolling effect but my buttons are not clickable. The view renders well, but when I tap the buttons it should print out 'tapped user1', for example but there is no effect.

EDIT: If I put the marquee modifier on the ScrollView as suggested, it causes the extremely buggy scrolling behavior. Ideally, this would just be a marquee'd HStack with a bunch of clickable buttons in it with no scrolling behavior built in, but the module doesn't seem to work without the ScrollView wrapping it.

I used this link to create a Marquee view modifier: https://swiftuirecipes.com/blog/swiftui-marquee

My code for the view is below:

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let users = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5", "user6"]
        return ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
             HStack {
                 ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
                     if user == users.first {
                         Button(action: {
                             print("tapped \(user)")
                         }, label: {
                             Text(user)
                         })
                     } else {
                         Text("•")
                         Button(action: {
                             print("tapped \(user)")
                         }, label: {
                             Text(user)
                         })
                     }
                 }
             }.frame(height: 20)
              .marquee(duration: 10)
         }
     }
 }
```

The code from the marquee tutorial is below:

```
struct Marquee: ViewModifier {
  let duration: TimeInterval
  let direction: Direction
  let autoreverse: Bool

  @State private var offset = CGFloat.zero
  @State private var parentSize = CGSize.zero
  @State private var contentSize = CGSize.zero

  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    // measures parent view width
    Color.clear
      .frame(height: 0)
      // measureSize from https://swiftuirecipes.com/blog/getting-size-of-a-view-in-swiftui
      .measureSize { size in
        parentSize = size
        updateAnimation(sizeChanged: true)
      }

    content
      .measureSize { size in
        contentSize = size
        updateAnimation(sizeChanged: true)
      }
      .offset(x: offset)
      // animationObserver from https://swiftuirecipes.com/blog/swiftui-animation-observer
      .animationObserver(for: offset, onComplete: {
        updateAnimation(sizeChanged: false)
      })
  }

  private func updateAnimation(sizeChanged: Bool) {
    if sizeChanged || !autoreverse {
      offset = max(parentSize.width, contentSize.width) * ((direction == .leftToRight) ? -1 : 1)
    }
    withAnimation(.linear(duration: duration)) {
      offset = -offset
    }
  }

  enum Direction {
    case leftToRight, rightToLeft
  }
}

extension View {
  func marquee(duration: TimeInterval,
               direction: Marquee.Direction = .rightToLeft,
               autoreverse: Bool = false) -> some View {
    self.modifier(Marquee(duration: duration,
                          direction: direction,
                          autoreverse: autoreverse))
  }
}

struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
  static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero

  static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
    value = nextValue()
  }
}

struct MeasureSizeModifier: ViewModifier {
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content.background(GeometryReader { geometry in
      Color.clear.preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self,
                             value: geometry.size)
    })
  }
}

extension View {
  func measureSize(perform action: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
    self.modifier(MeasureSizeModifier())
      .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self, perform: action)
  }
}

public struct AnimationObserverModifier<Value: VectorArithmetic>: AnimatableModifier {
  // this is the view property that drives the animation - offset, opacity, etc.
  private let observedValue: Value
  private let onChange: ((Value) -> Void)?
  private let onComplete: (() -> Void)?

  // SwiftUI implicity sets this value as the animation progresses
  public var animatableData: Value {
    didSet {
      notifyProgress()
    }
  }

  public init(for observedValue: Value,
              onChange: ((Value) -> Void)?,
              onComplete: (() -> Void)?) {
    self.observedValue = observedValue
    self.onChange = onChange
    self.onComplete = onComplete
    animatableData = observedValue
  }

  public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
  }

  private func notifyProgress() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      onChange?(animatableData)
      if animatableData == observedValue {
        onComplete?()
      }
    }
  }
}

public extension View {
    func animationObserver<Value: VectorArithmetic>(for value: Value,
                                                    onChange: ((Value) -> Void)? = nil,
                                                    onComplete: (() -> Void)? = nil) -> some View {
      self.modifier(AnimationObserverModifier(for: value,
                                                 onChange: onChange,
                                                 onComplete: onComplete))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the modifier on scrollview, it will fix your issue

Like this.

```
import SwiftUI
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let users = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5", "user6"]
        return ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
             HStack {
                 ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
                     if user == users.first {
                         Button(action: {
                             print("tapped \(user)")
                         }, label: {
                             Text(user)
                         })
                     } else {
                         Text("•")
                         Button(action: {
                             print("tapped \(user)")
                         }, label: {
                             Text(user)
                         })
                     }
                 }
             }.frame(height: 20)
             
         }
        .marquee(duration: 10)
     }
 }
```

Comment: This is close, but it changes the behavior of the marquee. The marquee is scrollable because it's in the scrollview and when you put the modifier on the scrollview, it causes Buttons generated by the ForEach to be cut off. I think this is happening because the width of the view containing all the buttons is greater than the width of the screen, which causes it to crop because it's in a scrollview. This cut off behavior doesn't happen when the modifier is on the inner HStack...not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I've tried removing the ScrollView in general, but this causes the marquee to render the view like: 'use...  •  use...  •  use...  •  use... ' and so on. Again, I think this is because the width of the containing view is greater than the width of the screen so it cuts off the users.

Comment: Can you drop a link that shows the button cutting off, I might get some idea looking at it.?

Comment: With the code in your answer, it renders as seen here: https://youtu.be/OTsb9yjbBDw They're still clickable but you can't see the whole button's text. The other issue with the code in this answer is that if I scroll in the area that the buttons aren't (to the left of the leftmost button or right of the rightmost button) the entire set of buttons just disappears (as seen at the end of the clip).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the modifier on the button `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` or similar with other button styles. If that doesn't work, then try using just the button label that you desire and add the modifier `.onTapGesture {your code}`

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these solutions worked. If you come up with a working solution in the next 24 hours before I have to award the bounty, I'll reward it to you!